# Memory monitor is disabled in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

[snap of android studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OVbT9.png)

I have checked all the options on the list mentioned here on 
https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/am-basics.html#byb

I also have tried to make it work on emulator as well as on device. Nothing seems to work .

Answer (score 0):

As per the image you have provided, You have paused the memory monitor. Click again on pause button and start debugging. It will show you the memory consumption.